# How do I use form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, authentication

I'm trying to create a form to create a user. Currently I have

```
- form_for @user do |f|
  = "Username"
  %br
  = f.text_field :username
  %br
  = "Password"
  %br
  = f.text_field :password
  %br
  = "Confirm Password"
  %br
  = f.text_field :password_confirmation
  %br
  = "Email"
  %br
  = f.text_field :email
  %br
  = f.submit "Submit app"
```

I keep getting the error `undefined method 'password' for #<User:0x8e20750>` 
User does have a method password=, but because I'm encrypting the password before I store it, there is no password method. Anyone have a work around or a fix?

Answer (score 0):

You should post your model as well, but I am guessing, that what you need is to add:

```
attr_accessor :password
```

On a side note, is there a reason you are doing your own Authentication logic? Maybe you should try complete solutions like Authlogic or Devise?

Also, please take a look on Formtastic Gem. It really helps to create forms.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with mdrozdziel that you might want to give Authlogic (not tried Devise myself) a shot.

When using form_for f.text_field :some_field is like saying text_field :model, :some_field. So :some_field needs to a field in your db or you need getter and setter methods.

as mdrozdziel said

```
attr_accessor :password
```

or you can define getter and setter methods in your model if you want more control.

```
#in your model
def password
   # return something
end

def password=(pwd)
   # set something
end
```